# How to reduce the height of select dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I'm having an issue with the select html tag. I have a project when I have a list that is too large, with so many elements. The problem is that I want to shrink the height of the dropdown box and I don't know how to do it.

Here is what happens when I click the select tag:

[image]

I want it to be smaller, like, show 10 elements at the time.

Here is my html:

```css
    .selectWrapper, .selectBrand {
        width: 60%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: "select";
        align-items: center;
            
        &::after {
            content: '';
            clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
            width: 0.8em;
            height: 0.5em;
            grid-area: select;
            justify-self: end;
            margin-right: 1em;
            background-color: #110F30;
            pointer-events: none;
            transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
        }
            
        &:focus-within {
            &::after {
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }
        }
            
        select {
            appearance: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 3em;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            padding-inline: 1em;
            align-items: center;
            grid-area: select;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            color: #535353;
            background: linear-gradient(145deg, #d3d3d3, 
            #fafafa);
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #a4a4a4,
            -10px -10px 20px #ffffff;
            
            &:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }         
    }
```

```html
    <div class="selectWrapper">
        <select name="typeSol" class="titSol" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <!-- More options -->
        </select>
    </div>
```

Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `onfocus`, `onblur`, and `onchange` events to change this. Where `this` represents the HTML DOM element.  You can change the values accordingly

```css
.titSol, .selectBrand {
        width: 60%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: "select";
        align-items: center;
            
        &::after {
            content: '';
            clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
            width: 0.8em;
            height: 0.5em;
            grid-area: select;
            align-self: end;
            margin-right: 1em;
            background-color: #110F30;
            pointer-events: none;
            transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
        }
            
        &:focus-within {
            &::after {
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }
        }
            
        select {
            appearance: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 3em;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            padding-inline: 1em;
            align-items: center;
            grid-area: select;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            color: #535353;
            background: linear-gradient(145deg, #d3d3d3, 
            #fafafa);
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #a4a4a4,
            -10px -10px 20px #ffffff;
            
            &:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }         
    }
```

```html
<div class="selectWrapper">
    <select name="typeSol" class="titSol" onfocus='this.size=8;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
        <!-- ...More Options -->
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, when I put that in my code, this is te result [https://i.imgur.com/mqBqB82.png](https://i.imgur.com/mqBqB82.png)

Comment: @GLPG35 are you applying any CSS, if so please add that to your OP.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: The HTML and CSS you provided doesn't seem to recreate the issue you just linked the img to

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the class in the scss. Now it should work.